# Calculation of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons that are for certain products. I am wanting to be able to have a total box at the bottom of the form which add's the total up of each radio buttons that is clicked. I know this can be done via the Value of the radio button and then using some javascript.

The problem is i dont think i can use that method as i need the values to be how they are in the code below so when i get sent the email from the form submit i can see what options the user has choosen.

Any suggestions without using javascript or using the values?

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;47.50</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;47.50 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;75 excl</span>
```

Is it possible to add something like `price="20"` etc for each radio button and then add these up?

**EDIT**

@Jamiec answer worked perfectly fine adding a extra "data-price" felid and totaling up using some javascript.

Ok so after playing around with Jamiec code i realised that it add's up the total of radio buttons that have been checked but are no longer checked. As i also have some javascript which does the following:

Only one radio button from `name="keystage1yr1"` can be selected 
Only one radio button from `name="keystage1yr2"` can be selected

But if any radio button from `name="keystage1save"` is selected then any radio button from `name="keystage1yr1"` and `name="keystage1yr2"` that has been selected will be deselected.

The problem is that with the javascript supplied by @Jamiec the total will still have the values of the `name="keystage1yr1"` and `name="keystage1yr2"` if `name="keystage1save"` is selected. I need it to just calculate the total from the radio buttons that are **selected**

**EDIT2** @Jamiec updated answer to not store the values in cache fixed the problem

Comment: You can not invent attributes, unless your going for HTML5. Wel you can, but it wouldnt be valid.

Comment: Wait, these are radio buttons so only 1 can be selected. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Jamiec no it does not need to calculate VAT. Only one can be selected of each set of 3 yes. But i am wanting the options which are checked to add up a total price.

Comment: @Matt - ah I see, there are 3 groups of radio buttons... working on an example for you now. Check back on my answer below in a few mins!

Comment: @Jamiec Sure didn't realise it wasn't on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Javascript, no - Definately not.

Parsing the text inside the span next to each radio using Javascript, yes - but quite tricky

Adding an extra attribute to the radio containing the raw amount, use Javascript, yes - not very hard

Adding an extra attribute (preferably `data-amount`), get using a library such as jQuery, yes - easy peasy lemon squeezy!

---

An example for you using jQuery.

Augmenting each of your radio's like:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper" data-price="25" /> <span>&#163;25</span>
```

Add a total field like:

```
<input id="total" type="text">
```

And use the following code.

```
var values = {}; // index to store the selection from each named group of radio's

$('input:radio').change(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  values[name] = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
  var total = 0.0;
    $.each(values,function(i,e){
        total += e;
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/UL2JP/

---

**Edit**, the code above does only add up those checkboxes which are checked, unfortunately, it caches what has previously been selected in the javascript object `values`. If you, through code, unselect some checkboxes, you need to re-calculate what is selected.

An update to this code appears to do what you describe in your comments:

```
var values = {};

$('input[name="keystage1save"]').click(function(){
    $('input:radio:not([name="keystage1save"])').prop('checked',false);
    values = {};
});

$('input:radio').change(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  values[name] = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
  var total = 0.0;
    $.each(values,function(i,e){
        total += e;
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/UL2JP/1/

---

**Edit 2**: Just a thought, there is no need really to cache the selected values, it would be faster to just calculate on the fly:

```
$('input[name="keystage1save"]').click(function(){
    $('input:radio:not([name="keystage1save"])').prop('checked',false);
});

$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var total = 0.0;
    $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
          total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/UL2JP/2/

Comment: Is it possible to add something like price="20" etc for each radio button and then add these up?

Comment: No, it would be valid HTML5 which is better ;)

Comment: @Matt - yes. Preferably stiick to the HTML5 connvention of `data-*` attributes. ie, `data-price`.

Comment: @Jamiec I dont really understand what you mean is it possible for you to eleborate. Also if using HTML5 that would mean older browsers wouldn't render it correctly?

Comment: @Matt - older browsers will render HTML5 just fine. Newer features of HTML5 such as more form fields will just render as textfields. The data-* attributes ive mentioned will be ignored, but will still be usable from javascript.

Comment: Apart from using a new attribute, your code loops over every value in the array each time the radiobutton is clicked. Might not really cause  a performance issue, but still :). But granted, great code :)

Comment: @saratis - No, it doesnt. It loops over the **selected** values. That is a maximum of 3 iterations (for 3 groups of radio's) if you have selected 1 radio from each group. ie, `values` only contains the selected price from each group of radio's.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, the values in the values array. And of course with 3 items its not a problem, but I was assuming this was part of a larger list. And also, it was more a principal matter than anything else :) Nice job.

Comment: @Jamiec it does work great but one small issue i have some javascript working where if you click one of the radio buttons name="keystage1save" if you have selected any of the above radio buttons they get deselected. With your code the total still calculates them. Is it possible to only calculate the radio buttons that are marked as "checked". saratis this is part of a larger list of radio buttons.

Comment: @Matt - why don't you update your question with what's really going on, and i'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do three things:

> - Use AJAX en do it properly serverside
> - Create an array with the IDs of the radiobuttons and values, and onClick lookup the value and add that to the total
> - Misuse the ID attribute to store the value in, and write some JS, to add it up. For instance #val1_1 #val2_4 etc. (not recommended)

Would you like me to eleborate on one of these options.

If you do not want to use AJAX, I would suggest going for option two, that's rather elegant.

HTML:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" id="ks1p" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" id="ks1c" name="keystage1yr1" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" id="ks1cp" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" id="ks2p" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>

//etc..
```

JS:

```
var prices= new Array();
prices["ks1p"]=1;
prices["ks1c"]=2;
prices["ks1cp"]=3;
//etc
var lastPrice = new Array();
lastPrice ["keystage1yr1"]=0;
lastPrice ["keystage1yr2"]=0;
//etc
var totalPrice = 0;
$('.radio').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var name= $(this).attr('name');
   if(lastPrice[name] != 0){
     totalPrice = totalPrice  - lastPrice[name];
   }
   lastPrice[name] = prices[id];
   totalPrice = totalPrice +  prices[id];
   alert(totalPrice);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nggLr/

Comment: It would be great if you could help out a bit futher yes. Is it possible to add something like price="20" etc for each radio button and then add these up?

Comment: Again, not valid HTML4. If you use the array approach you wil have a nice and valid, elegant solution. I will explain.

Comment: I *kind of* like this solution, other than you have to maintain the prices of everything in a javascript array. Means its easier to update the HTML display price and forget the total price is calculated elsewhere. Granted my solution has the same issue, but at least the prices are all together in the markup... Also HTML4, really? 1996 called and asked for it's outdated and irrelevant spec back!

Comment: Lol ok, I meant !=HTML5 when I said HTML 4. But I still dont agree with your solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are building this using some sort of server side code, use that to calculate the total price

Comment: I am not using any server side code, I am building it onto Wordpress, this is a custom page with a order form on for products which get selected by radio buttons and then submited. Just need to be able to have values for when the form gets submited but also values for the price of each which can be added up.

Comment: Not really what he asked for, and not really constructive, but a valid option.

Comment: perhaps you could add another element with simple double values. and use JS to loop around and count those which correspond to the selected radios